How can I get Masters of Science (Mathematics) with Bachelor of Philosophy? I need the Masters to attain Ph.D in Mathematics
I am a philosophy student with the aim to get Doctor of Philosophy in Mathematics. I pursued philosophy in the first place, because it's core courses offered in our school from my understanding was foundational to the world from critical thinking to having a good life. I see philosophy has a lot of opportunities I can proceed to law, theology, divinity, education and many more. But so far Mathematics has been my interest because I have this interesting original research paper I want to publish someday and it tackles about God and Mathematics. This is also one of the reasons I started studying Philosophy.

Where do you wish to study? Which country or countries? And, what math courses have you taken?

Sharing details here about your paper would probably be a mistake.

@Buffy
I am from Philippines. I am currently a philosophy student. I am planning to study in UP Diliman someday.

But so far Mathematics has been my interest because ... it tackles about God and Mathematics - There is no known branch of mathematics which "tackles about god"

Did you check out the requirements for the masters (in mathematics) program you want to get admitted to? Does it require a bachelors in mathematics (or another STEM subject)?

Is this paper with an academic supervisor, or by yourself? Have you done the work rigorously, or do you just "know it will work" and will "fill in the detail later"? The claim to mix god and mathematics screams crackpot to me. People have tried to prove/disprove god in the past, but often run into issues with the assumptions they used. While the logic may be fine, the axioms they assume are not and you end up with "garbage in, garbage out".

I don't entirely understand what the question is asking. If you want a masters in mathematics, the first step is largely to apply. Getting the prereqs for a master's may require you to go back and do some undergrad classes.

Good luck. Take some time to plan a few ways you’ll earn a living.

@NAMcMahon, there might be some sub fields of philosophy that would ask and consider questions about god's place in math.

@Buffy, there could be, but for the field not to be crackpottery the practitioners would have to have a deep understanding of mathematics (and likely other STEM fields). This is something that's fairly safe to assume an undergraduate student of philosophy doesn't have. If they are doing it by themselves it likely falls under crackpot. If they have a supervisor who is directing the research it is less likely, but still could be the supervisor wanting to do something outside their field of expertise and using a student project as an excuse. And christianity is quite dominate in Philippines.

If OP wishes to become an academic, it would be better that they understand any concerns early to avoid them engaging in a sunk cost fallacy and turning themselves into a true crackpot rather than an overeager student. I could imaging focusing themselves on only this as impacting their chances when applying for masters/PhDs, or when looking for supervisors. And if they are doing their own research its particularly risky since they lack training in mathematics and actual academic research practices.

Since you want to study at UP Diliman, a high quality research institution, it should be easy enough for you to visit the campus (one of several) and ask your questions there.
My fear, however, is that you don't have sufficient background in math to enter a masters program. Even in the US, where a philosophy undergraduate degree is much broader than just philosophy, you would be missing many important math courses. This may not be true for you, of course, but the math department at UP Diliman could guide you best.
You are correct that philosophy as a major part of a broad undergraduate education is a good basis for many things, but math (and a few others) require a special way of thinking that isn't typically part of a philosophy degree other than a formal course in logic. I used to joke (not a joke) that the history and philosophy majors would eventually wind up being the bosses of the geeks.
You need specific information that the university's math department can provide.
